Why is "cloth" an obscenity in Levin's "This Perfect Day"?
Ira Levin's This Perfect Day portrays a dystopian society where everyone is drugged into peaceful acceptance of the conformity of the society. "Hate" and "Fight" are strong curse words (equivalent to "Hell" and "Fuck"), but there's another mild obscenity "cloth" which appears to mean something like "crap" or "bullshit." The reason for "Hate" and "Fight" to be bad words is obvious, but I don't quite see how "cloth" came to be word for a bad thing. (The people in this society wear clothes made out of "paplon"—some sort of paper-like substance I suppose—if that helps.)

Wait, "hell" is a curse word?

In 1967, the network wanted Kirk's line "Let's get the hell.out on here" censored.  The past is a different country

@Clockwork You know I'm old and I don't understand why no reels or shorts on social media will show the word "sex", and I still think "hell" is borderline.

@ToddWilcox No one knows what the censors want or how they work, it's all hearsay. Since they can't debunk it, they play it safe.

It appears that "cloth" refers to lies in the context of the culture. It might come from the use of the Yiddish word for every day clothing - shmata - that also can mean something discarded, worthless, useless. I heard it used only in a derogatory sense among the Yiddish speakers of my childhood.

A usage that Ira Levin might be familiar with - thanks.  Will accept as soon as the timer expires

@andrew It rang a bell, and yes,Levin was Jewish.

I suspect that it is also something that covers the truth, like clothes cover flesh.

It could also be a dig at the Clergy/religious behaviour, as in "man of the cloth".

Perhaps it comes from "whole cloth," with the idiomatic meaning of "nonsense" or "fiction."

A tenuous link is also the word "yarn", which can mean "story". One could imagine in this fictional world the term "cloth" as falsehood came from the idea of a lot of yarn woven together, ie a bunch of lies or fiction.

I wonder if this is the same sense of "stuff" as in "stuff and nonsense".

@PhilFreedenberg I would tend to agree with you, the uses of "cloth" in "This Perfect day" (except of course where the meaning is just simply actual cloth) are similar to those of "whole cloth" for us. But I'd like to remark that whoever translated it into French did not try to find a uniform translation for this use of "cloth". Once it was just omitted, once translated into the mild french expletive "Zut" ("darn" rather than "damn"), once with "histoires", which normally means "stories" but in that context would mean "ridiculous stories", "nonsense". Clearly, the translator did not care much.

Just to suggest an alternative reading; if the citizens of this world only wear paper clothes (presumably as they're cheap and discardable), it might make sense to inculcate the idea of "cloth" as something taboo or rude.
It could, in this manner, be seen as yet another angle of oppression and thought control; driving people away from seeking the higher luxury that expensive textile clothes would be over the paper clothes they're made to wear.
